# Post data from a website to another website via webextension

Tags: javascript, plugins, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an architectural question, whether it is possible to post data from website A to website B via the help of a webextension.

I am relatively new to webextension (browser plugin development) and wanted to find out..

Use case for example: Take a password from website a, store it in the plugin and open the new website and automatically log in to the website.

It is just an extended password manager, isn't it?